# parse currency name to integer values in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing, currency

I have a currency value as follows say,

`$6.041 billion USD (2006)` or `US$6.041 billion (2009)[1]` or `€6.041 billion (2010)[1]`.

I want to parse the currency value in such a way that I want to store it in three different variables i.e. `$number, $currency, $year` (i.e) `$number = 6,041,000,000` and`$currency = "euro"` and `$year = 2010`.

The problem is that the string might have `€` or `$` or `USD`. But I need to parse them accordingly.

Also I might end up having `million` also. According to that succeeding zeros should vary. Also I might or might not have decimal points in the currency.  i.e `6.041 billion` or `6 billion`.

How to handle all the cases and store the result in the three variables I need?

similarly how to handle `£(67.1) million (2011)[1]` `HK $ 648 million (2006)` `22,440,000, 1,325.26 crore (US$241.2 million) [4].`?

I am thinking of a brute force solution to handle each case one by one.
But that is not a apt one.

Is there any simplest way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

You could try running regular expressions something like this (untested):

```
if(preg_match('/([$€])([\d\.]+)\s?([\w]+)[^\(]*\((\d+)\)/',$value,$matches)){
    switch($matches[1]){
        case '$':
            $currency = 'dollar';
            break;
        case '€':
            $currency = 'euro';
            break;
        // and more for more currencies
    }
    $number = $matches[2];
    switch($matches[3]){
        case 'billion':
            $number = intval($number*1000000000);
            break;
        case 'million':
            $number = intval($number*1000000);
            break;
        // and more for more multipliers
    }
    $year = $matches[4];
}
```

Remember to add all the possible currency symbols you need to support in the first pair of square brackets in the regular expression `[$€]`.

Comment: I am facing difficulties while parsing because my sample currency values are like this.. £(67.1) million (2011)[1], HK $ 648 million (2006), 22,440,000, 1,325.26 crore (US$241.2 million) [4]. How to handle all the case. if we have year, I want year to be set else it should be empty.

Comment: You should make sure your question includes all the possible variations. No-one can design a regular expression to help you without all the information.

Answer (score 0):

Untested and I am sure there are more elegant ways to do things, but this should work:

```
<?php

echo parseCurrency('$6.041 billion USD (2006)');


function parseCurrency($input){
 if(strpos($input, 'USD') || strpos($input, '$')){
     $currency = 'USD';
     $floatVal = (float) get_string($input, '$', ' ');
 }
 elseif(strpos($input, '€')){
     $currency = 'EUR';
     $floatVal = (float) get_string($input, '€', ' ');
 }
 else{
     $currency = 'undefined';
     die();
 }

 if(strpos($input, 'billion'){
    $number = $floatVal * 1000000000;
 } 
 elseif(strpos($input, 'million'){
    $number = $floatVal * 1000000;
 }
 else{
    $number = 'undefined';
    die();
 }
 if (preg_match('/\\([12][0-9]{3}\\)/', $input, $years)){
    $year = $years[0];
 }
 else{
    $year = 'undefined';
    die();
 }
 return $number . ', ' . $currency . ', ' . $year;
}

//used to find million or billion
function get_string($string, $start, $end){
 $string = " ".$string;
 $pos = strpos($string,$start);
 if ($pos == 0) return "";
 $pos += strlen($start);
 $len = strpos($string,$end,$pos) - $pos;
 return substr($string,$pos,$len);
}
```